# EF6 Temporal Table for Auditing

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Is there a way to record who did the change within the Temporal table? I can see the date ranges but I can't see a way of adding a new column to the schema?

Answer (score 0):

Temporal tables don't track "who" only "when".  You can add a column to the table to track who performed the last modification, setting that value in an override to DbContext.SaveChanges() or in a Trigger.